# Does DotNetOpenAuth OpenId Provider actually work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, openid, dotnetopenauth

Using [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/). I'm trying to get the Provider endpoint to work. When I set a break point on the code to accept OpenId request:

```
IRequest request = OpenIdProvider.GetRequest();
```

This returns null when I use a relying party to call the provider. I hosted the solution and its the same problem. I added localhost to the whitelist also.

But the point is, the request reaches the provider but it is saying that there was no openId request. Here is the provider [endpoint](http://dev1.ncu.edu.jm/openid/provider), if you want to test it.

Comment: it works for most other people that have tried it, including myself: http://codesprout.blogspot.com/search/label/dotnetopenauth

Comment: @Lirik, if you point an RP to mine, does it return anything? I'm also talking about the provider. You implemented RP only in your blogpost

Comment: Nevermind, I see what you're doing... I've never tried it. However, I would use the `HttpRequestInfo` overloaded [`GetRequest` method](http://docs.dotnetopenauth.net/v3.3/html/M_DotNetOpenAuth_OpenId_Provider_OpenIdProvider_GetRequest_1_a5a08f2e.htm) to ensure that there is a request which can be processed. Otherwise I'm not sure how you will actually know when there is a request which you can retrieve.

Comment: @Lirik, yea, there is a request coming in, its just that the provided API from DNOA `OpenIdProvider.GetRequest()` returns null.

Comment: what I'm saying is that if you actually call `OpenIdProvider.GetRequest(HttpRequestInfo request)` and specify the request, then you might actually get something back. I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/blob/v3.4/src/DotNetOpenAuth/OpenId/Provider/OpenIdProvider.cs) and `GetRequest()` calls `GetRequest(HttpRequestInfo...)` with the current channel. Trace through and ensure that the Channel has a request in it.

Comment: @Lirik: Still didn't get anything from the method :(. I did : `OpenIdProvider.GetRequest(new HttpRequestInfo(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request));`
`Request` had information also.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be confusing the "OP Identifier" or Claimed Identifier with the OP Endpoint.  Your page claims to be an OP Endpoint, which it probably is.  But no one can test that directly.  You need to type an OpenID *identifier* into an RP to kick start the process, and that identifier tells the RP which OP Endpoint to talk to.  So quite likely, if you're typing http://dev1.ncu.edu.jm/openid/provider into your RP, the RP is sending a discovery request to that URL and not seeing any *identifier* there.

Try pointing an Identifier to that OP Endpoint and passing that identifier to the RP instead.

Also, [activating logging](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki/Logging-and-debugging) on the RP and OP will surely yield some helpful tips.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. I want it to behave like google. Do I need Identifiers?

Comment: I saw your explaination http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557430/dotnetopenauth-how-to-implement-a-simple-openid-provider/3562476#3562476. I understand the differences now, but I have no idea how to make an OP Idenfifier be static. I just want to create a button and automatically point to the endpoint